# Arquivo com caracteres estranhas

Tags: c, string, arquivo

Eu tenho uma string que recebe um valor de entrada pelo teclado e um arquivo que contem uma string. O que preciso fazer é comparar a string digitada com a string do arquivo e conferir se são iguais, mas fui ver que tipo de string do arquivo estava tirando e tava vindo com caracteres estranhos (botão de play, '@' e seta pra baixo). O código em tese parece funcionar, contudo gostaria de saber porque a string que estou trazendo pra comparar com a digitada pelo usuário está vindo com esses caracteres.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{

setlocale(LC_ALL,"portuguese");

FILE *arquivo;
char frase[6];
char frase2[6];
int i;

if(arquivo = fopen("teste.txt", "r") == NULL)
{
    puts("ERRO! IMPOSSÍVEL ABRIR O ARQUIVO");
}
else
{
    printf("Digite a frase: \n");
    gets(frase);

    fgets(frase2, 6, arquivo);
    puts(frase2);

    if(i = strcmp(frase, frase2) == 0)
    {
        puts("Encontrado");
    }
    else
    {
        puts("Não encontrado");
    }

}

fclose(arquivo);
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: O que tem no arquivo?

Comment: O arquivo possui o nome "Lucas", ou seja, quando o usuário digitar string no teclado, é para fazer uma comparação. Contudo, quando eu puxo essa string do arquivo para ver o que está acontecendo sai umas caracteres todas estranhas. Ai então o programa sempre diz "Não Encontrado". Já verifiquei e o arquivo tá com texto ANSI e mesmo assim não adiantou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>

main(){

    setlocale(LC_ALL,"portuguese");

    FILE *arquivo;
    char frase[6];
    char frase2[6];
    int i;

    if(arquivo = fopen("teste.txt", "r") == NULL)//Uma estrutura 
    //condicional só aceita valores boleanos e você está atribuindo
    //então coloque assim

    //arquivo = fopen("teste.txt", "r");

    //if(arquivo == NULL)
   {
        puts("ERRO! IMPOSSÍVEL ABRIR O ARQUIVO");
   }else{
        printf("Digite a frase: \n");
        gets(frase);//não é recomendável usar gets() pois não terá uma
        //controle sobre o tamanho da string que o usuário digitar

        fgets(frase2, 6, arquivo);
        puts(frase2);

        if(i = strcmp(frase, frase2) == 0)//como disse antes sem atribuição em 
        //estruturas condicionais, tire o 'i' e como ele não irá servir para nada 
        //no código apague ele lá no ínicio

        //if(strcmp(frase, frase2)){
            puts("Encontrado");
        }else{
            puts("Não encontrado");
        }

    }

    fclose(arquivo);
    getch();//getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Acho que não tem mais erros.

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado! Esse daqui me deu uma dor de cabeça!